# Cómo traerme un dato del cypress config como variable y luego cambiar su contenido

Tags: typescript, api, url, puertos, cypress

Hola mi inconveniente es el siguiente. Genere un spec en cypress que trae una respuesta api con un puerto distinto al que está configurado en la baseUrl del cypress.config. Este punto lo logré solucionar de está manera.

```
**before(()=>{
 Cypress.config("baseUrl",'http://localhost:9801');
})**
```

y lo luego lo reestablezco así:

```
**after(()=>{
 Cypress.config("baseUrl",'http://localhost:17000');
})**
```

Hasta ahí todo bien porque manualmente yo coloco las ip en donde voy a correr la prueba. Ahora que pasa cuando subo mi prueba a la nube Azure automaticamente me cambia la ip de la maquina donde va a correr la prueba y solo la cambia en mi cypress.config.

```
 **e2e: {
testIsolation:false,
experimentalRunAllSpecs: true,
// We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
// You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
},
specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/specs/**/*.spec.js',
baseUrl: 'http://111.111.111.11:17000',
},**
```

Al modificarse la ip en el config, ya las ip de mi spec no coinciden. Deberían quedar así:

```
****before(()=>{
Cypress.config("baseUrl",'http://111.111.111.11:9801');
```

})**

```
**after(()=>{
 Cypress.config("baseUrl",'http://111.111.111.11:17000');
})****
```

¿Como podría traerme esa url que está en el config como variable y como pudiese cambiarle el puerto si me la traigo como variable?
O cualquier otra forma que me quieran sugerir. La verdad no encuentro como solucionar este problema.

Comment: Hola Vanessa, podrías hacerlo leyendo/configurando [variables de entorno](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env). Una idea de como implementarlo la podes [obtener acá](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#From-a-plugin).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Hola quisiera compartir como lo pude resolver por acá. Quizas le sirva de ayuda a otras personas.
Para traerme la variable del config:

```
let baseURL =  Cypress.config("baseUrl");
```

Y para modificar esa variable use la funcion slice, que le resta caracteres del principio y el final:

```
let url = baseURL.slice(7,-6);
let baseUrlPromo = baseURL.slice(0,-5) + '1245';
```

Luego sustituí las variables donde las necesita:

```
before(()=>{
    Cypress.config("baseUrl", baseUrlPromo);
  })
 after(()=>{
     Cypress.config("baseUrl",baseURL);
    })
```